# Conda update while building Docker fails

Tags: docker, conda

I receive the following errors while building a docker image. I am using Docker Desktop (OSX). The url indeed works but Conda is giving me these errors when I run docker build. I have tried setting a different channel (e.g., conda-forge) but am still receiving these errors. The downloaded bytes are different each time.

Is there an issue with Docker's network connection?

```
#0 124.4 CondaError: Downloaded bytes did not match Content-Length
#0 124.4   url: https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/linux-64/pytorch-1.11.0-py3.8_cuda11.3_cudnn8.2.0_0.tar.bz2
#0 124.4   target_path: /miniconda/pkgs/pytorch-1.11.0-py3.8_cuda11.3_cudnn8.2.0_0.tar.bz2
#0 124.4   Content-Length: 1097104794
#0 124.4   downloaded bytes: 124742074
```

```
#0 151.7 CondaError: Downloaded bytes did not match Content-Length
#0 151.7   url: https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/python-3.8.5-h7579374_1.conda
#0 151.7   target_path: /miniconda/pkgs/python-3.8.5-h7579374_1.conda
#0 151.7   Content-Length: 51673600
#0 151.7   downloaded bytes: 19806597
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:12.0.0-runtime-ubuntu22.04
WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget git && apt-get clean

RUN git clone https://github.com/db0/nataili.git .
# Check out a specific version of the above repository
RUN git checkout 6c2f1862bacf25b6bc74e95e3174ca45a116f85b 
RUN echo "boto3>=1.21.32">>requirements.txt

# Download and install Miniconda
RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
RUN bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /miniconda

# Add miniconda to the PATH
ENV PATH=/miniconda/bin:$PATH

# Update conda and install any necessary packages
RUN conda update --name base --channel defaults conda && \
    conda env create -f /app/environment.yaml --force && \
    conda clean -a -y

# Install conda environment into container so we do not need to install every time.
ENV ENV_NAME ldm

COPY ecs_run.py /app/

SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "ldm", "/bin/bash", "-c"]

ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "--no-capture-output", "-n", "ldm", "python", "ecs_run.py"]
```

I tried to run docker build and am receiving this error.

Comment: Did you solve your error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a network/downloading issue.

If this problem persists I suggest to:

1. download the PyTorch package with `curl`

and then install it in offline mode:

2. `conda install --offline pytorch_package`